# How to do http Crud operations in in $scope.myfunction() function?

Tags: angularjs-scope, meanjs

**I used meanjs generator to get this code**

Mycode :- which Queries data from servercontroller .But I need to use Http request to get data from Api server. So i tried Code Like the Following with Http

*SuperherosController.js*

```
 angular.module('superheros').controller('SuperherosController', ['$scope','$http', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Superheros',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Superheros,$http) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;
// *Find a list of Superheros*
        $scope.find = function() {
   //Actual code with out Http request 
           // $scope.superheros =  Superheros.query();
   /// *The code i tried with  Http and injected dependencies*
```

//Line 56:13
     $http.get('http://api.xxx.com/superheros').success(function(data){
                    $scope.superheros = data;
                });
             };
            }
        ]);

**By Above modifications http.get making request but there is an error raising :-

ERROR**

> ***$http.get(...).success is not a function
>   $scope.find@http://localhost:3000/modules/superheros/controllers/superheros.client.controller.js:56:13***

*Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an object but got an array*  with some referencing to angular domain

Could You Please let me know whats wrong in My code .. or how can i fix this Problem ? 
Thanks For Help In Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of your modules must have same order in the function too

```
function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Superheros)
```

$http comes after $scope because you defined your modules in that order

Comment: Yeah I got My Mistake ... Thanks Hareesh !!